# emgu CV C# with Capture class

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

I have been working on a fun coding project that uses emguCV along with C# and .NET . The problem I am having is trying to initialize the Capture() class in my code. Every time I try  to initialize Capture it throws an Exception:

```
    The Type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an Exception
    Exception type: System.InitializationException from Emgu.CV.dll
```

here is the C# code I have:

```
class Vision
{
    private Capture cap;
    private HaarCascade haar;
    private Form1 form;

    public Vision()
    {
            form = new Form1();
            cap = new Capture();
            haar = new HaarCascade("C:\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
    }
    public void faceDetect()
    {
        using(Image<Bgr, Byte> nextFrame = cap.QueryFrame())
        {
            if(nextFrame != null)
            {
                Image<Gray, Byte> grayframe = nextFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
                var faces = grayframe.DetectHaarCascade(haar, 1.4, 4, HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(nextFrame.Width / 8, nextFrame.Height / 8))[0];
                foreach(var face in faces)
                {
                    nextFrame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(0, double.MaxValue, 0), 1);
                }
                form.setImage(nextFrame.ToBitmap());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The references for the code are:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Emgu.CV;
    using Emgu.Util;
    using Emgu.CV.Structure;
    using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
    using System.Drawing;
```

Everytime the Exception happens, it shows up at the
        cap = new Capture();

I have also tried to set the camera index for the Capture class as 0,1,2... and had no luck with that either. I also thought maybe that since I have windows running on a mac that it is not detecting the webcam, but then I did download the most up-to-date drivers for windows to access the camera. I thank everyone who helps in advance! :-)

Comment: EmguCV should have some unmanaged dependencies on OpenCV, are you sure everything is installed?

Comment: yes, I downloaded the correct software and added the dependencies according to the tutorial that came with it.

Comment: I know, I necroposter, but in Emgu CV 310 Capture is replaced by VideoCapture. I lost 2 days to find it.

Answer (score 0):

It probably occurs when the unmanaged DLL dependencies fail to load. Try the following things:

1. Make sure you are using the correct version of EmguCV, i.e. if you are building the Solution in x86 mode, you should have the x86 version of EmguCV, and similarly for the x64 version.
2. Make sure the OpenCV DLLs are in your PATH (or directly in the bin directory, if this is a Console/WinForms/WPF app.)

You can find how to do it [here](http://fewtutorials.bravesites.com/entries/emgu-cv-c/-emgu-cv-invoke-threw-an-exception-solution).

You can also refer to official documentation [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very "classic" error for first user of EmguCV, so don't worry, it's easy to solve!

You need to install MSVCRT for your version of Visual Studio. Also, it could be that you didn't put the DLL files in your project with a "Copy if newer".

See all the details on [the official emguCV site](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an x64 machine, you need to change your project settings. Go to project settings -> build -> Target platform -> x64. More details here: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_EMGU_C_Sharp